# Point on Argand Diagram

Tags: complex-numbers

In the Argand diagram shown below the complex numbers $-1+i, 1+i, 1-i, -1-i$ are represented by the square $ABCD$. The equation of the diagonal $BD$ is $y=x$.  The complex number $k+ki$ where $-1<k<0$ represent the point $E$, which is the fourth quadrant.

[image]

$EFGC$ is a square such that $F$ lies of $AB$. The line $GE$ meets the line $CD$ produced at $H$ such that $H$ is represented by $-2-i$. Show that the point $F$ is given by $\frac{-k}{k+2}+i$.

I have been trying to solve the above question by multiplying $EC$ with $i$ to get $EF$.  But my answer does not match with the above

Comment: What is $S{}{}$?

Comment: Doesn't the question say $E=k+ki$, how can $E$ be $ \frac{k}{k+2} +i$?

Comment: S should be C, right? Your idea to multiply was good, it is clear there is a rotation of 90 degrees. But the rotation is anticlockwise, so you have to multiply by (-i). Moreover, the center of rotation is not in origine.

Comment: @Quippy It should read F.  I fixed the typo.

Comment: @ZiauddinAhmedMohammed "*multiplying EC with i to get EF*" $-$ Did you use the other condition that $G,E,H$ must be collinear? The problem can be solved for $k$, so $F$ can be written in multiple ways.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

An important detail in the analysis of this problem is *not* included in the diagram.  As pointed out in the comment by **dxiv**, we should also consider the line segment $ \ HF \ \ . $  We will come to its significance shortly.

We should first see how much of the diagram can be taken at face value.  We can check that if the quadrilateral $ \ CEFG \ $ is  a square, then the point $ \ F \ $ is in fact always on the line $ \ AB \   $ .  The segment $ \ EC \ $ has direction $ \ \langle \ 1 - k \ , \ -1 - k \ \rangle \ $ [or complex number $ \ \alpha \ = \ (1 - k) - ( 1 + k) \ i \ $ ] and length $ \  |\alpha| \ = \ \sqrt{(1-k)^2 \ + \ (1 + k)^2} \ = \ \sqrt{2 + 2k^2} \  \ . $  For segment $ \ EF \ $ to be perpendicular to $ \ EC \ \ , $ it must have the direction $ \ \langle \ 1 + k \ , \ 1 - k \ \rangle \ $ [or $ \ \beta \ = \ (1 + k) + (1 - k) \ i \ ] \ $ ; its length is $ \  |\beta| \ = \ \sqrt{(1+k)^2 \ + \ (1 - k)^2} $ $ = \ |\alpha|  \ . $  [We can also calculate that $ \ Re( \ \alpha·\overline{\beta} \ ) \ = \ [ \ (1 - k)·(1 + k) \ - \  ( 1 + k)·(1 - k) \ = \ 0 \ \ , $ which also shows that $ \ EF \ \perp \ EC \  \ . \ ] \ $

The location of $ \ F \ $ is then $ \ [ k + k·i ] \ + \ [(1 + k) + (1 - k) · i] \ = \ (1 + 2k) + i \ \ , $  so the diagram is reliable.  [We can also check that the length of the diagonal of the square, $ \ FC \ \ , $ is $ \ \sqrt{( \ 1 - [1 + 2k] \ )^2 \ + \ (1 - [-1])^2} \ = \ \sqrt{4k^2 + 4} $ $ = \ \sqrt2·|\alpha| \ = \ \sqrt2·|\beta| \ \ . \ ] \ $  So $ \ \Delta FEC \ $ is a right isosceles triangle and the center of the square $ \ P \ $ , which is the midpoint of $ \ FC \ \ , $ $   \frac{1 + (1 + 2k)}{2} \ + \ \frac{i + [-i]}{2} \ = \ 1 + k  \ , $ does lie on the $ \ x-$axis.  The line segment $ \ PE \ $ is then an altitude of $ \ \Delta FEC \ \ . $

So we can confirm that the $ \ x-$coordinate of point $ \ F \ $ is given by $ \ X \ = \ 1 + 2k \ \ $ and that any choice of $ \ -1 \ < \ k \ < \ 0 \ $ would produce a square $ \ CEFG \ \ , $ as **Cye Waldman** finds.  However, the problem statement gives a particular expression for $ \ X \ \ $ which *does not* apply generally to the geometrical situation.  This suggests that a specific value for $ \ k \ $ is being sought, as noted in **dxiv**'s remarks.  (This is why the straightforward multiplication by $ \ i \ $ to produce a 90º rotation was not enough to resolve the problem -- we *always* have a square for all permissible values of $ \ k \ . \ ) $

There are a couple of ways we can find the value for $ \ k \ \ . $  We have determined that $ \ P \ $ bisects $ \ FC \ \   $ and $ \ HP \ $ is given to be perpendicular to $ \ FC \ \ , $ so $ \ \Delta HPC \ $ and $ \ \Delta HPF \ $ are congruent right triangles.  The hypotenuse $ \ HC \ $ has length $ \ \sqrt{( \ 1 - [-2] \ )^2 \ + \ ( \ [-1] - [-1] \ )^2} \ = \ 3 \ \ , $ so we have the length of hypotenuse $ \ HF \ $ as
$$ \sqrt{( \ [1 + 2k] \ - \ [-2] \ )^2 \ + \ ( \ 1 - [-1] \ )^2} \ = \ \sqrt{( 3 + 2k)^2 \ + \ 4} \ = \ 3  \ \ .  $$
From this, we obtain the quadratic equation
$$ 9 \ + \ 12k \ + \ 4k^2 \ + \ 4 \ \ = \ \ 3^2 \ \ \rightarrow \ \ 4k^2 \ + \ 12k \ + \ 4 \ \ = \ \ 4·(k^2 \ + \ 3k \ + \ 1) \ \ = \ \ 0 \ \ , $$
for which the solutions are $ \ k \ = \ \frac{-3 \ \pm \ \sqrt{9 \ - \ 4}}{2} \ \ . $  The relevant value for this problem is $ \ -1 \ < \ k = \frac{-3 \ +  \sqrt5}{2}  \approx  -0.382 \ < \ 0 \ \   $  (making $ \ X \ = \ \sqrt5 \ -  \ 2  \ \approx \ 0.236 \ \ . ) $

Alternatively, the line $ \ HE \ $ has direction $ \ \langle \ k - (-2) \ , \ k - (-1) \ \rangle \ = \ \langle \ k +  2  \ , \ k +  1  \ \rangle \ \ , $  while the line  $ \ HP \ $  has direction $ \ \langle \ (1 + k) - (-2) \ , \ 0 - (-1) \ \rangle \ = \ \langle \ k + 3 \ , \ 1  \ \rangle \ \ . $  As these two vectors should have the *same* direction, it must be that
$$ \frac{k \ + \ 1}{k \ + \ 2} \ \ = \ \ \frac{1}{k \ + \ 3} \ \ \Rightarrow \ \ k^2 \ + \ 4k \ + \ 3 \ \ = \ \ k \ +  \ 2 \ \ \Rightarrow \ \ k^2 \ + \ 3k \ + \ 1 \ \ = \ \ 0 \ \ , $$
giving us the same quadratic equation we determined above.

As $ \ \Delta FHC \ $ is isoceles, we should have $ \ HP \ \perp \  FC \ \ . $  We calculate the scalar product of the directions of these segments' vectors to be
$$ \langle \ k + 3 \ , \ 1 \ \rangle \ \centerdot \ \langle \ (1 + 2k) - 1 \ , \ 1 - [-1] \ \rangle \ \ = \ \ (k+3)·2k \ + \ 1·2 \ \ = \ \ 2k^2 \ + \ 6k \ + \ 2 \ \ , $$ which is again an appearance of a multiple of the quadratic polynomial for which we have found a zero.

However, the poser of the problem is not *quite* done with us, as we are asked to demonstrate that $ \ X \ = \ \frac{-k}{k \ + \ 2} \ \ . $  We can accomplish this by direct numerical calculation, but it may suffice to show that
$$ 1 \ + \ 2k \ \ = \ \ \frac{-k}{k \ + \ 2} \ \ \Rightarrow \ \ (1 \ + \ 2k)·(k \ + \ 2) \ \ = \ \ -k \ \ \Rightarrow \ \ 2k^2 \ + \ 6k \ + \ 2 \ \ = \ \ 0 \ \ , $$
(once again!) for which we know that $ \ k = \frac{-3 \ +  \sqrt5}{2} \ \ $ is a solution.

Answer (score 0):

You correctly realize that $F$ is at $ {CE}$ rotated by $90^{\circ}$, or $e^{i\pi/2}=i$. The correct solution is then

$$F=(C-E)e^{i\pi/2}+E$$

or

$$F=1+2k+i$$

I have verified this numerically for random values of $k\in (-1,0)$.

Comment: $k$ is uniquely determined by the conditions of the problem, so the question remains whether $\;1+2k+i\;$ is equal to the other expression *for that particular value of* $\,k\,$.

Comment: @dxiv Point taken, but the solution I gave is valid for any $k$, as indicated. I saw the point of the problem was to find $F$, not $k$.

Comment: The problem asks to prove that $\,F = \frac{-k}{k+2}+i\,$, which is only true for the unique value of $\,k\,$ that satisfies both conditions of the problem. That requires also using the second condition $\,\left|F-H\right|=\left|C-H\right|=3\,$.